# comparing files using python

Tags: python

I have 29 text files as follows

File 1

```
12313 : 23546

        12313

        23214

        32465
```

File 2

```
13132 : 23546

        12323

        32125

        32125

        32121

        .

        .

        .
```

I would like to have python script which computes intersection between these files

ideal result as follow

```
12313 : 23546

13132 : 23546
```

Comment: What does the `12313:` have to do with anything?  I'm a little confused where it comes into play ...

Comment: What's in the other 27 files that makes that output mean anything at all?

Comment: hi all the 27 files are similar to files i mentioned in question..can you please tell how to do make python script thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean intersection as used in Set.

Assuming that these are all numbers in files, load them into a Set.

- http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

Intersection:

```
from sets import Set
x = Set([1, 3, 4,9])
y = Set([1,3])
print x & y
Set([1, 3])
```